# How to access foreign key description in ASP.Net 4.5 Web Forms model binding

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.5

In ASP.Net 4.5 Web Forms, I have a grid which uses the new Model Binding feature, backed from Entity Framework:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="uxGrid" ItemType="SAData.SelfAssessment" DataKeyNames="SelfAssessmentID" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" PageSize="2"
        SelectMethod="GetSelfAssessments" CellPadding="5" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

This duly lists out all Assessments within the DB, including their destination, which is a FK to the obviously-named Destination table. The DynamicField is set to display the DestinationID, but I really want to see the Destination *name* from the actual Destination table.

I've tried a couple of variations, e.g.

```
<asp:DynamicField DataField="Destinations.DestinationDescription" HeaderText="Destination" />
```

(where Destinations is the table)

and

```
<asp:DynamicField DataField="Destination.DestinationDescription" HeaderText="Destination" />
```

(where Destination is the Navigation property).

Both methods result in "The table 'SelfAssessment' does not have a column named 'Destinations.DestinationDescription'." or similar.

My GetSelfAssessments method uses the .Include method to, well, include the Destinations table, but to no avail.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, fixed it - use a asp:BoundField to Destination.DestinationDescription, not a asp:DynamicField and it's fine. Also, there was no need to .Include("Destination") either, although I wonder whether I should to prevent an assumed lazy load.

Now, sorting on Destination is another matter...